# Create Right-Click Dialog in .NET Application

Tags: c#, dialog, right-click

I would like to create a function, similar to the "Add to Dictionary" option in Microsoft Word, within my .NET application.  I basically want to highlight a word within a textbox, right-click on it, and have an option to "Add to Custom Dictionary".  Is this possible?  I can't figure out how to get a custom menu to appear on right-click.

Comment: Is this winforms? You might find http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-customize-default-contextmenu-of-a-textbox-control-in useful..

Comment: To start you off you can suscribe to the textboxes `mousedown` event then use the selection start and selection length properties to get the current selection (can parse this to a word perhaps), not sure how to go about making the menu though. Probably only a google search away..

Comment: What have you tried? A `ContextMenu` and an Event Listener on the `MouseDown` event should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use a context menu and bind it to your control, if I understand you right.

```
ContextMenu myContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
// Set various options for the context menu

myControl.ContextMenu = myContextMenu;
```

Comment: Here is a sample from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenu.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was quite easy.  I did not realize that there was a ContextMenu item in the Visual Studio Toolbox.  So I just did the following:

```
1) Drag the contextMenu onto the WinForm
2) Assign the contextMenu to the textBox in question
3) Add items to the contextMenu.
4) Assign shortcut keys to each item in the contextMenu.
```

I am still trying to figure out how to fire the individual items in the contextMenu.